# What language is used in This War of Mine?

Tags: this-war-of-mine

Though inspired by Bosnian War, the city of Pogoren in *This War of Mine* is fictional. But the radio announcements in cutscenes from *Last Broadcast* DLC sound like some real language to me:

Did they use a real language or just made it up?

Answer (score -1):

It seems like it's a little gibberish, along with some Slavic words sprinkled in, certain words and names are spelled like how words in Slavic are spelled, for example "Informacji" or "pogorenu", pretty sure I heard "kako" at some point too, so it's probably something eastern Slavic maybe, heavily distorted and with a bit of gibberish, I think. It's also fair to note that there are certain words written on the walls, like in the loading menu and such that are Polish words.

Comment: What do you base this on? Do you speak a Slavic language? Why do you think it's gibberish?

Comment: on the fact that the game is eastern european in its setting, yes, it doesnt seem decipherable.